# Doctrine resultsetmapping should return array

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have this query:

```
select count(*) as total_count, sum(total) as total_value, status from invoice group by status;
```

when I execute it in the database I get the following:

[image]

I want to achieve the same using Doctrine2 but the following code only returns one row:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('total_count', 'totalCount');
$rsm->addScalarResult('total_value', 'totalValue');
$rsm->addScalarResult('status', 'status');

$query = $this->getObjectManager()->createNativeQuery('
  select count(*) as total_count, sum(total) as total_value, status from invoice group by status', $rsm);

$result = $query->getResult();

return $result;
```

This is the result of the above:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'totalCount' => string '1432' (length=1)
      'totalValue' => string '55447.80999999999' (length=2)
      'status' => string 'paid' (length=4)
```

Comment: try with `$query->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);`

Comment: @Matteo that gives me `The query returned a row containing multiple columns. Change the query or use a different result function like getScalarResult().`

Comment: I think doctrine fetches multiple rows for you. Try with `getSingleResult()`. See [the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/reference/query.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$result = $query->getScalarResult();
```

Instead of :

```
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `getResult` doctrine will try to fetch all matching rows for you. You need to use Doctrine's [`getSingleResult`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/reference/query.html#getsingleresult) if you don't want the result to be an array of arrays.

So for you simply:

```
$result = $query->getSingleResult();
```

You can also limit the number of results to throw a `QueryException` if more or none are returned:

```
$query->setMaxResults(1);
```